# How to sum up values of different keys if the key is find in a list of sublists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, sublist

First of all English is not my mother tongue.

I have txt file which is like this : It is a list of word with numerical score  :

```
id;word;pos;neu;neg
0;***;21;127;0
1;vraiment;407;156;37
2;oiseau-à-berceau;102;259;0
3;Stoph;95;308;37
4;Conscience;372;144;35
5;rançonnement;0;635;433
6;provenir;304;227;47
7;esthétique;285;54;1
8;traversée;360;167;38
9;avant toute chose;241;108;34
10;sucrée;52;276;0
11;Lasker-Schüler;146;284;0
12;difficile;0;47;866
13;adjuration;300;44;40
14;Besnier-Boeck-Schaumann;0;39;315
15;sir Sacheverell Sitwell;38;277;0
16;Maria Callas;235;311;0
17;sorbre;118;302;225
```

I have a list of sublists  like this where each list contains some words :

```
[['trouver', 'très', 'esthétique'], ['pêche', 'peu'], ['gros', 'prise', 'là'], ['prise', 'puis', 'borne', 'cela', 'voir'], ['derrière', 'télé', 'cela', 'aller'], ['voir', 'système', 'cela', 'aller', 'être', 'difficile', 'faire', 'plus', 'sorbre'], ['laudrel', 'être', 'mourir', 'hier', 'soir'], ['venir', 'lo']]
```

I store the txt file in my script in a dictionnairy :  which looks like this :

```
{'vraiment': ['407', '156', '37\r\n'], 'oiseau-à-berceau': ['102', '259', '0\r\n'], 'Stoph': ['95', '308', '37\r\n'], 'Conscience': ['372', '144', '35\r\n'], 'rançonnement': ['0', '635', '433\r\n'], 'provenir': ['304', '227', '47\r\n'], 'esthétique': ['285', '54', '1\r\n'], 'traversée': ['360', '167', '38\r\n'], 'avant toute chose': ['241', '108', '34\r\n'], 'sucrée': ['52', '276', '0\r\n'], 'Lasker-Schüler': ['146', '284', '0\r\n'], 'difficile': ['0', '47', '866\r\n'], 'adjuration': ['300', '44', '40\r\n'], 'Besnier-Boeck-Schaumann': ['0', '39', '315\r\n'], 'sir Sacheverell Sitwell': ['38', '277', '0\r\n'], 'Maria Callas': ['235', '311', '0\r\n'], 'sorbre': ['118', '302', '225']}
```

for each sublist in my list , I check if any of its words is my dictionnary and if it finds a word in my sublist in the dictionnary , it retrieve the numerical value of each word in my list and sum the value of each word for each column.

For example  :

```
  [  'voir',  'système', 'aller', 'être', 'difficile', 'faire', 'plus', 
   'sorbre']  : 'difficile' ['0', '47', '866\r\n']  
                 'sorbre': ['118', '302', '225']
```

this sublist above has two word present in my dico, I would like to sum each together each index of all the words in my sublist and do it for each sublist in my list;

I am expecting this for each list of my sublist   to get the sum of score in the first index(0) and then the sum of the score in the second index(1) and the sum of the score  for the third index(2) for all the word present in my dico and my sublist:

```
 [  'voir',  'système', 'aller', 'être', 'difficile', 'faire', 'plus', 
   'sorbre']  :  pos : 118, neu : 349, neg 1091
```

This is my script  :

```
from itertools import islice
dico = {}
#lexique = open('lexique.txt', 'rb')JeuxdeMotsPolarise.txt'
with codecs.open('lexique_entrainement.txt', 'r', 'utf-8', errors = 'ignore') as lexique:
for ligne in islice(lexique, 31, None):
    #print(ligne)
    ligne = ligne.split(';')
    #print(ligne)
    #print(ligne[-4:])
    dico.update({ligne[-4]:ligne[-3:]})
print(dico)

somme_V0 = []
somme_V1 = []
somme_V2 = []


for k, v in dico.items():
    for subl in Lemme_filtre2:
        for w in subl:
            if k == w:
                somme_V0.append(int(v[0]))
                somme_V1.append(int(v[1]))
                somme_V2.append(int(v[2]))
                #print(subl)
                print(str(subl) + " : " + " a un score pos de: " + str(sum(somme_V0)) + " un score de neu de : " + str(sum(somme_V1)) + " et un score de neg de : " + str(sum(somme_V2)))118  349  1091
```

the output is this  :

```
['trouver', 'très', 'esthétique'] :  a un score pos de: 285 un score de neu de : 54 et un score de neg de : 1    
['voir', 'système', 'cela', 'aller', 'être', 'difficile', 'faire', 'plus', 'sorbre'] : a un score pos de: 285 un score de neu de : 101 et un score de neg de : 867
 ['voir', 'système', 'cela', 'aller', 'être','difficile', 'faire','plus', 'sorbre']     :  a un score pos de: 403 un score de neu de : 403 et un score de neg    de : 1092
```

The output is not the same as what i imagined,  I think it is summing up all the value of the words in all the sublist , Do you have any  idea how can I fix it , I should be like this :

```
['trouver', 'très', 'esthétique'] :  a un score pos de: 285 un score de neu de : 54 et un score de neg de : 1   
['voir', 'système', 'cela',  'aller', 'être', 'difficile', 'faire', 'plus', 'sorbre'] :  a un score pos de: 118 un score de neu de : 349 et un score de neg de :  1091
```

I would like also if the one the third sum for each sublist is higher than the other two , I want to display the list and the higher score alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this will help.

```
dico = {"a":["1","2","3"],"b":["2","2","3"],"c":["1","3","4"],"d":["1","3","5"]}
Lemme_filtre2 = [["a","b","l","p"],["l","f","l","p"],["a","g","d","p"],["p","c","o","p"]]

for subl in Lemme_filtre2:
    somme_V0 = []
    somme_V1 = []
    somme_V2 = []
    for w in subl:
        if w in dico:
            somme_V0.append(int(dico[w][0]))
            somme_V1.append(int(dico[w][1]))
            somme_V2.append(int(dico[w][2]))
    if len(somme_V0)!=0:        
        print(str(subl) + " : " + " a un score pos de: " + str(sum(somme_V0)) + " un score de neu de : " + str(sum(somme_V1)) + " et un score de neg de : " + str(sum(somme_V2)))
```

output

```
['a', 'b', 'l', 'p'] :  a un score pos de: 3 un score de neu de : 4 et un score de neg de : 6
['a', 'g', 'd', 'p'] :  a un score pos de: 2 un score de neu de : 5 et un score de neg de : 8
['p', 'c', 'o', 'p'] :  a un score pos de: 1 un score de neu de : 3 et un score de neg de : 4
```

Comment: Good Morning, thank you , but i would like the score for each sublist having a word in the dico , in your example the list  ["l","f","l","p"] has score whereas  , the letters in the list are not appearing in the dico.

Comment: In your example only: ['a', 'b', 'l', 'p']  and  ['a', 'g', 'd', 'p'] shoudl be print.  I would like the score of each list  which word appear on the dico.  so the output would be like  :   ['a', 'b', 'l', 'p'] :  a un score pos de: 3 un score de neu de : 4 et un score de neg de : 6  and  ['a', 'g', 'd', 'p'] :  a un score pos de: 2 un score de neu de : 5 et un score de neg de : 8

Answer (score 0):

**Here is your final code:**

```
# Consider below as your input text
text_file = """
id;word;pos;neu;neg
0;***;21;127;0
1;vraiment;407;156;37
2;oiseau-à-berceau;102;259;0
3;Stoph;95;308;37
4;Conscience;372;144;35
5;rançonnement;0;635;433
6;provenir;304;227;47
7;esthétique;285;54;1
8;traversée;360;167;38
9;avant toute chose;241;108;34
10;sucrée;52;276;0
11;Lasker-Schüler;146;284;0
12;difficile;0;47;866
13;adjuration;300;44;40
14;Besnier-Boeck-Schaumann;0;39;315
15;sir Sacheverell Sitwell;38;277;0
16;Maria Callas;235;311;0
17;sorbre;118;302;225
"""

lst = [['trouver', 'très', 'esthétique'], ['pêche', 'peu'], ['gros', 'prise', 'là'], ['prise', 'puis', 'borne', 'cela', 'voir'], ['derrière', 'télé', 'cela', 'aller'], ['voir', 'système', 'cela', 'aller', 'être', 'difficile', 'faire', 'plus', 'sorbre'], ['laudrel', 'être', 'mourir', 'hier', 'soir'], ['venir', 'lo']]
foo =  ({i.split(";")[1]:i.split(";")[2:] for i in text_file.split("\n") if i}) # Spliting the text content and creating a dictionary

z = {}
for i in lst:                                                   # Loop through the lst
    for j in i:                                                 # Loop through the element in inner list
        if j in foo:                                            # check if inner value is in dict foo
            # Here we are creating our final result dictionary
            if z.get(repr(i)):   # check if the key i already exists in dictionary z, if yes then we will add the values of the dictionary. repr is used to use list as a key of dictionary.
                t = [int(a) + int(b) for a,b in zip(z[repr(i)] ,foo[j])]    # zip takes one element at a time of of both list. we are adding it and storing it in a list
                z[repr(i)] = t # Adding the list t to dict z
            else:
                z[repr(i)] = foo[j] # If the value is not existing in dict z then we just keep the output of foo
print (z)                                                       # Printing our final dictonary

# Below I have looped through the result to print it as required
for k, v in z.items():
    print (f"{k}:  a un score pos de: {v[0]} un score de neu de : {v[1]} et un score de neg de : {v[2]}") # Printing our dict one by one
```

**Result**

```
# Dict output
{"['trouver', 'très', 'esthétique']": ['285', '54', '1'], "['voir', 'système', 'cela', 'aller', 'être', 'difficile', 'faire', 'plus', 'sorbre']": [
118, 349, 1091]}

# Final output
['trouver', 'très', 'esthétique']:  a un score pos de: 285 un score de neu de : 54 et un score de neg de : 1
['voir', 'système', 'cela', 'aller', 'être', 'difficile', 'faire', 'plus', 'sorbre']:  a un score pos de: 118 un score de neu de : 349 et un score de neg de : 1091
```

Comment: Thank you ,  Could you please explain again how this part work : if z.get(repr(i)):
                t = [int(a) + int(b) for a,b in zip(z[repr(i)] ,foo[j])]
                z[repr(i)] = t
            else:
                z[repr(i)] = foo[j]

Comment: I have another questionis possible te retrieve only the string , in the k. For example  :['trouver', 'très', 'esthétique']   :  'trouver', 'très', 'esthétique'

Comment: I have edited the post and added an explanation as requested. You can add print statements in between to check the values printed at the required stage.

Comment: @kely789456123 - You can use k.replace() function or regex re module. 
Here is an example using replace function:

print (f"{k.replace('[','').replace(']','')}:  a un score pos de: {v[0]} un score de neu de : {v[1]} et un score de neg de : {v[2]}")


*I hope my answer counts now. :)*

Comment: You can also use dict comprehension to generate the entire z dict as follows:
z = {repr(i): foo[j] if not z.get(repr(i)) else [int(a) + int(b) for a,b in zip(z[repr(i)] ,foo[j])] for i in lst for j in i if j in foo}

Comment: Glad to help, if this answer solved your problem please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark next to the answer. see: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more information

Comment: Thank you very much. now I understand how it works.  I tried to print the  biggest value and use this  :  for k, v in dico_phrases.items():
  if v[0] > v[1] and v[0] > v[2]:
   print(k + ": a une polarité positive de "+ str(v[0]))
  elif v[1] > v[0] and v[1] > v[2]:
   print(k + ": a une polarité neutre de "+ str(v[1]))
  elif v[2] > v[0] and v[2] > v[1]:
   print(k + ": a une polarité négative de "+ str(v[2]))    => for the first list , it prints  : 54 wheras it is 283  the biggest value, do you perhaps know why it gives 54 ???

Comment: I went through your for loop and if conditions, its correct.
*for k, v in z.items(): 
    if v[0] > v[1] and v[0] > v[2]: 
        print(k + ": a une polarité positive de "+ str(v[0])) 
    elif v[1] > v[0] and v[1] > v[2]:
        print(k + ": a une polarité neutre de "+ str(v[1])) 
    elif v[2] > v[0] and v[2] > v[1]:
        print(k + ": a une polarité négative de "+ str(v[2]))*

If you can share dico_phrases, I could suggest something

Comment: dico_phrase is the same as z  : {"['trouver', 'très', 'esthétique']": ['285', '54', '1\r'], "['voir', 'système', 'cela', 'aller', 'être', 'difficile', 'faire', 'plus', 'sorbre']": [118, 349, 1091]} ;   so far this is my  output  :['trouver', 'très', 'esthétique']: a une polarité neutre de 54
['voir', 'système', 'cela', 'aller', 'être', 'difficile', 'faire', 'plus', 'sorbre']: a une polarité négative de 1091   => It returns  "54" for the highest value  of first list of words but the highest is 283.

Comment: @kely789456123 - Its because you are not converting the string object in the list to int. Use below code to convert all objects in list v to int.
v = list(map(int,v)) immediately after your for loop before if condition.
map is used to apply int function on each element of v.

If you find this entire answer helpful, then please give a upvote and mark this answer as helpful. :)

Comment: hello, I would like to know the in the part where the final dico is filling , i would like to add that if the word find in the list not appeared in the dico_lexique , put it in the dictionnary but with value as 0,0,  0 ;     dico_phrases[repr(i)] = dico_lexique[j] # If the value is not existing in dic0 put it but with value as 0,0,0, for the 3 values,    Can you help me ?